# C++ 11 Приоритет потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить приоритет потока в С++ 11 версии?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению, никак. Необходимо использовать API платформы. В классе `std::thread` может быть метод `native_handle` возвращающий дескриптор потока, пригодный для использования с такими API.

Comment: Кстати да. Странно, что все библиотеки потоков не поддерживают приоритет потока. Что std::thread, что pthread. Хотя казалось бы что может быть естественнее... :-(